# Delete data from canvas in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

how do i delete data from a figure when it is used in tktinter via FigureCanvasTkAgg? 
I have tried to clear the figure with cla, clf and to delete the canvas with .delete, .clear. 
My code: (If you have any advise how i can improve my code let me now. This is my first project in coding)

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg

#createplot
fig_CDF = Figure(figsize = (6, 5), facecolor = "white")
axis_CDF = fig_CDF.add_subplot(111)

canvas_CDF = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig_CDF, master = window_main)
canvas_CDF._tkcanvas.pack(side = tk.TOP, fill = tk.BOTH, expand = 1)
canvas_CDF.get_tk_widget().place(x=400,y=50)

#plotdata
axis_CDF.plot(datax, datay, label = "data",marker=".", linestyle = "")
canvas_CDF.draw()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: is this full code ? Where do you  create window `tk.Tk()` ? Where do you use `mainloop()` to run it ? And where do you clear figure? Maybe you clear it in wrong place? Did you try to remove values from `datax` and `datay` and `.draw()` it againg ?

Answer (score 0):

In this code I added three buttons which shows three methods - all of them need `canvas_CDF.draw()` to redraw element in window.

- first replaces data in `plot` and it removes points from chart but it still show axes.
- second clears axis - so it remove data and set axis to 0..1
- third clears figure - it removes even axis.

First version needs

```
plot = axis_CDF.plot(...)
```

to have access to data.

I use `random` only to create some data.

---

```
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import random

# --- functions ---

def replace_data():
    datax = []
    datay = []

    #datax = range(10)
    #datay = [x/10 for x in random.sample(range(10), 10)]

    plot[0].set_data(datax, datay)
    canvas_CDF.draw()

def clear_axis():
    #axis_CDF.clear()
    axis_CDF.cla()

    canvas_CDF.draw()

def clear_figure():
    fig_CDF.clear()
    #fig_CDF.clf()

    canvas_CDF.draw()

# --- main ---

window_main = tk.Tk()

datax = range(10)
datay = [x/10 for x in random.sample(range(10), 10)]

# create plot
fig_CDF = Figure(figsize=(6, 5), facecolor="white")
axis_CDF = fig_CDF.add_subplot(111)

canvas_CDF = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig_CDF, master=window_main)
canvas_CDF._tkcanvas.pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=True)
canvas_CDF.get_tk_widget().pack()

# plot data
plot = axis_CDF.plot(datax, datay, label="data", marker=".", linestyle="")
canvas_CDF.draw()

# buttons
b = tk.Button(window_main, text='Replace data', command=replace_data)
b.pack()

b = tk.Button(window_main, text='Clear axis', command=clear_axis)
b.pack()

b = tk.Button(window_main, text='Clear figure', command=clear_figure)
b.pack()

window_main.mainloop()
```